# What does aspnet keep overwritting my onclick attribute?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a button on the form.  During Page_Load event I add a new onclick attribute to the button via code behind.  However when I inspect the button in firefox my attribute is not there and is being replaced with:

onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("button_modal_search", "", true, "modalSearch", "", false, false))'

here is the tag before I run the app:

here's my code behind:
button_modal_search.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return showSearchSpinner()")

Anyone know how I can prevent the attribute from being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET indeed overrides your `onclick` attribute, but does provide the [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property to allow you to specify your own client-side behavior:

```
button_modal_search.OnClientClick = "return showSearchSpinner();"
```

If the value of that property is constant, you can also specify it as an attribute in the button markup itself.

Comment: I created a new app, adding only a button and the attribute was not overwritten so it seems as though it doesn't always override.  Also trying to figure out why it is overriding in my case.

Comment: @nate, probably because ASP.NET cannot rely on the default submission behavior of your button. Maybe it's a `LinkButton`, or maybe its `UseSubmitBehavior` property is set to `false`, for instance.

Comment: @nate, ASP.NET should still generate its own `onclick` attribute, but that should include the code you provide in `OnClientClick`. That property has always worked for me (and for others according to a quick Google search). The problem might lie somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property `OnClientClick`: `button_modal_search.OnClientClick="return showSearchSpinner();"`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> button_modal_search.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return
>   showSearchSpinner()")

Above code is ok. If you do not want to postback to server, you just need to return **false** from javascript function.

Otherwise, it'll post back to server after running the **showSearchSpinner** function.

```
function showSearchSpinner(){
   // do something
   return false;
}
```

**Note:** You do not need to worry about ASP.Net replacing onclick event - `onclick='javascript:WebForm_... false, false))'`.

Basically **showSearchSpinner** javascript function intercepts ASP.Net click event, when you click on button_modal_search button.

Comment: ASP.NET does not always leave `onclick` alone, see [the UseSubmitBehavior property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx) for an example.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've never heard of `UseSubmitBehavior`. I learn new thing today. Thanks!